# sql help to find out multiple entries

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `t1` with the values

```
col1 col2 
1     2
1     4
1     4
2     4
2     4
3     5
3     5
4     3
4     3
5     1
5     1
5     6
5     6
```

I need to get the output as

```
1     2
1     4
5     1 
5     6
```

That is when `col2` has multiple entries I am interested in those records only.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
select col1, col2 
from t1
where col1 in (select col1 from t1 group by col1 having count(distinct col2) > 1)
group by col1, col2
```

The query should be pretty self-explanatory.